# SDL C++ game programming help (simple)

Tags: c++, sdl, game-development

I am working on a space shooter, and I cannot figure out how to make bullets continue firing to the end of the screen after I release the space bar. As of now, if I press the spacebar it shoots, when I release it, the bullet stay where they lefft off. Here are my classes which are called in order in main().

```
class Projectile : public Character
{
private:
    float xVel;
    float yVel;
    float x;
    float y;

public:
    void init();
    void keys();
    void move();
    void show();

}bullet;

void Projectile::init()
{
    x=315;
    y=305;
    xVel=0;
    yVel=0;
}

void Projectile::keys()
{
    bool shoot = true;
    Uint8 *keystates = SDL_GetKeyState( NULL );
    if(keystates[SDLK_SPACE])
    {             
        yVel-=14;             
    }
}

void Projectile::move()
{
    x=x+xVel;
    y=y+yVel;
    xVel=0;
    yVel=0;
    if(y<0)
    {
        x=charx;
        y=chary;              
    }
}

void Projectile::show()
{
    apply_surface(x-5,y-2,jizz,screen);
    cout << y << endl;
}
```

Comment: Does `apply_surface(x-5,y-2,jizz,screen);` apply jizz on the surface of the screen?

Comment: yeah... its a space shooter of an exotic type, and my 'bullets' are jizz....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's easy.

Don't do this (in Projectile::move()) :

```
xVel=0;
yVel=0;
```

And the bullet will keep moving.

Another problem is here:

```
if(keystates[SDLK_SPACE])
{             
    yVel-=14;             
}
```

Basically, you shouldn't do `-=`. Either replace it with `yVel = -14` (all bullets will always move with constants velocity) or detect "key down" moment (i.e. key hasn't been pressed in previous frame, and is pressed in current one), and only then do `-= 14`. This kind of thing (detecting a keyup/keydown event) might be simpler with if you process key events you receive (in your main loop) instead of calling `SDL_GetKeyState`.

Answer (score 0):

```
xVel=0;
yVel=0;
```

In your move method, you change the x and y coordinates and then set the velocities back to 0. This is why your bullet stops moving. While you are pressing Space you are constantly subtracting 14 from the Y-Velocity. You don't want to reset the velocities to 0.